# vb hex color codes

Tags: vb6, colors, hex

I want to do this:

```
    Const COLOR_GREEN = &H00FF00
    Me.Label1.BackColor = COLOR_GREEN
```

There is a problem however in that vb automatically decides to convert &H00FF00 to &HFF00 so I get this instead:

```
    Const COLOR_GREEN = &HFF00
    Me.Label1.BackColor = COLOR_GREEN
```

The decimal value COLOR_GREEN is now -256 instead of 65280 and so the background is black instead of green! This is annoying as I can perfectly well set the color in form design mode using #00FF00.

What is the equivalent in vb of setting a color to #00FF00 in the form design mode?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you tried the literal `&H0000FF00&`? The following code works just fine for me:

```
Const COLOR_GREEN = &H0000FF00&
Me.Label1.BackColor = COLOR_GREEN
```

Of course, VB 6 automatically collapses it to this, which still works just fine because the two values are *completely equivalent* numerically:

```
Const COLOR_GREEN = &HFF00&
Me.Label1.BackColor = COLOR_GREEN
```

**The trick is that the value needs to be declared as a `Long`, rather than an `Integer`.** Putting the ampersand (`&`) after the numeric literal accomplishes this.

That also explains why you're seeing a value of -256 instead of the 65280 that you expect. The value 65280 is too long to fit in an `Integer`, and when it overflows that data type, VB 6 wraps it around again, producing -256.

It's also worth noting that hexadecimal literals in VB 6 will not be equivalent to those that you are probably familiar with from the web and HTML programming. Instead of the RRGGBB notation that you find there, **VB 6 uses BBGGRR notation, or `&H00BBGGRR&`**, the same as the native Win32 `COLORREF` structure where the low-order byte is red, rather than blue.

---

Of course, do note that for standard color values like the one you've shown here, you're probably better off using the VB literals, such as `vbGreen`:

```
Me.Label1.BackColor = vbGreen
```

Comment: Yes that does work for green. I've also just found that `Const COLOR_GREEN = "&HFF00" works too! But how about FFF200 which should give yellow, vb won't allow &HFFF200& as it drops the last & to give &HFF200 which gives the color cyan not yellow!

Comment: @David: Yeah, that's an entirely different problem. Try the `RGB()` function, which accepts integer values corresponding to each of the red, green, and blue component values. So, for example, the following would get you the same color yellow as `&HFFFF20` **:** `Me.Label1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 32)`

Comment: I've just discovered the whole RGB vs BGR issue! That explains everything.

Comment: @David: If you need a compile-time constant, then it doesn't matter what notation you use. Just convert the hexadecimal notation into VB's standard `Long` notation that it uses for colors. But the "entirely different" problem seems to be that you are using `&H00RRGGBB&` notation, instead of `&H00BBGGRR&` notation. VB 6 is not the same as HTML. (Edit: Ah, yeah. And I just posted that. Yes, indeed.)

Comment: @David: VB6 won't allow &FFF200& as it drops the last & to give `&HFFF200`.  But note the leading `FFF`.  VB6 realises that the number is too big to fit into a 16bit int and promotes it to a 32bit long.  You can always do `Const COLOR_GREEN As Long = &H00FF00&` to show your intent of having a long.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot preserve the leading zeros in vb's hex notation.
Numeric literals (inclding `&H*`) default to 16bit integers, for a 32bit constant literal suffix with `&` to implicitly state its a long;

```
Const COLOR_GREEN = &HFF00&

?COLOR_GREEN
 65280
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Colortranslator

```
             dim myColor as new  Color
               myColor=ColorTranslator.fromHTML("#ff0000") 'Red color
```